# How to set headers on every request in Cypress using cy.intercept

Tags: cypress

I am trying to add a request header to every api request generated in Cypress. I have a version that works using `cy.server` but this is being depricated, so I am trying to replace it with `cy.intercept`. I don't see any errors when I run this code, but I don't see the header added to my requests either:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  
  cy.intercept('*',(req) => {
    console.log('MATCHED INTERCEPT')
    req.headers['my-test'] = 'TEST'
  })
})
```

I can see the log text 'MATCHED INTERCEPT' in the console, so I know that the intercept is matching something....

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Does it work if you pass in the header via the `RouteMatcher` object? For example, `cy.intercept({url: '*', headers: {'my-test': 'TEST'}})`

Comment: @natn2323 No it doesn't work like this either :-(

Answer (score 3):

I think you will not be able to see the new header after intercepting, as per their documentation :

[image]

Hope this was useful

Comment: The Note is quite confusing. I do not see the header in the Network console as described in their documentation however my server does receive the header values. Do you know how that is?